# AzureAD/User is not able for logon in services

Tags: windows, active-directory, azure-activedirectory, rclone

I am trying to run a service with AzureAD/User, but it is not letting me to add that user in below and run the service.

Service-Logon-configuration:

[image: Service-Logon-configuration]

But it is showing me below error when I run service after.

[image: Error when starting the service]

Available users in the list to select for logon service:

[image: Available users in the list to select for logon service]

Can some help me with the error? How can I run a service with AzureAD\User?